# Wordpress default contact form

Tags: php, contact

I would like to add contact form on my blog, however as I need only one, I would like to avoid using any external plugin. Does wordpress have some simple functionality for this ?

From my research, I didn't find anything suitable, except coding my own plugin or page template.

Thank you

Comment: No, WP doesn't have any form feature in core.

Comment: WordPress doesn't have anything built in for contact form, however you can develop a very basic and simple contact form if you don't want any heavy weight plugin.

Answer (score 0):

While Jetpack is a plugin, it's developed by Wordpress and has contact forms as standard.
There are some other useful features such as stats, etc. so it's definitely worth a look.

https://jetpack.com/

Comment: Thank you. Yes, jetpack has lot's of features, but it's pretty heavyweight form my website. I would maybe rather use Contact form 7 which is well maintained plugin, but if wordpress has something build it, I would rather use this option

Comment: There is nothing native built into Wordpress although you could obviously develop something using the 'wp-mail' function (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/)
I used to use CF7 but now tend to use Jetpack on my sites (for the other features such as sharing, stats, etc.) but that's just personal preference.